# How to find BSSID on a page using curl and grep?

Tags: bash, curl, grep

There's a textfile containing a list of bssid/name of devices. Why doesn't the following line work? It just outputs nothing.

`curl --silent https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/raw/master/manuf | grep c4:71:54`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `grep` to be case insensitive, you need to specify the `-i` flag:

```
$ curl --silent https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/raw/master/manuf | grep -i 'c4:71:54'
C4:71:54        Tp-LinkT        Tp-Link Technologies Co.,Ltd.
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide the correct pattern to the grep command. It is case-sensitive unless you use "grep -i ...". I believe the list of bssid/names of devices are in Upper-case. Therefore, the correct command is:

```
curl --silent https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/raw/master/manuf | grep C4:71:54
```

or, to ignore case-sensitivity within grep:

```
curl --silent https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/raw/master/manuf | grep -i c4:71:54
```

Comment: What does this add when compared to the existing answer?